# azure web app settings reverted to arm template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Today I saw something really strange with my azure web site. My site was originally deployed using an ARM Template that configured various application settings.

After the initial deploy one of the settings was manually changed via the portal. Today that setting was reverted back to the original value used in the template.

Should that even be possible? I checked audit/activity logs to see if anyone changed it, and the audit logs are empty.

What is going on here, anyone have an idea?

Comment: What is the portal setting that you changed? Web Apps might get redeployed during VM patches/failures. MS will use the same deployed package that is originally deployed when this happen. I would assume that portal settings should remain the same but if the ARM template is also changing this value then it probably overwrote the setting you manually changed.

Comment: It was a custom app setting, a connection string for sendgrid.

Answer (score 1):

That should not be happening. Azure will never automatically redeploy your ARM template.

Some possibilities that could have led to this:

1. Someone redeployed your ARM template, which would cause settings to be reset
2. Maybe when you made the setting change, it was never actually applied, e.g. if 'save' wasn't click, or some error happen.

I'd suggest applying you setting change again, and making sure that it is in fact applied. It should not get reverted by magic.